# Copying an adorned image to the clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard, bitmapimage, adorner

I have a `System.Windows.Controls.Image` which is decorated with a couple of adorners. Now I want to copy the adorned image to the clipboard. So far I have this line of code:

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(myImage as BitmapImage);
```

However, this only copies the image itself; the adorners are not included. Is there a way to include the adorners?

EDIT: Here's some code showing how I adorn `myImage`:

```
MyAdorner myAdorner = new MyAdorner(myImage);
AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myImage);
adornerLayer.Add(myAdorner);
```

`MyAdorner` is a subclass of `System.Windows.Documents.Adorner`. I don't think the specifics of the implementation are important.

Comment: how do you generate the adorners? can you show some code?

Comment: I haven't used adorners before, but from reading the documentation it seems that there is no relation between a UIElement and an Adorner. It just takes the desired location from the UIElement and then renders. So the only possibility I see is to take a screenshot. Last time I checked the framework doesn't provide you with a method to do this, you'll have to do some Interop calls.

Comment: [Every Adorner is an UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner.aspx)

Comment: @Davide Piras: I have now added a few lines of code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to render your image and its adorners to a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653503.aspx) and then convert that bitmap to an image that can be added to the clipboard.

See the example at the bottom of the page, it should cover everything you need.